# How to show that $y$ (function of $t$) is a Periodic Function (or not)?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The function $y(t)$ satisfies the DE below, where $d$ and $g$ are Real constants and at $t=0$ then $y=y_0$ and $y'(0)=0$:

$$\ddot{y}(d+y)+\dot{y}^2+gy=0$$

If we don't have a solution (analytical or numerical) for $y(t)$ can we determine whether it is a periodic function, that is $y(t)=y(t+T)$, or not?

Comment: Second order DE needs two boundary conditions.

Comment: Did you, by any chance, happen to derive the DE from [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/718924/confusion-regarding-oscillation-of-water-in-a-straw)?

Comment: @eyeballfrog Correct. I've edited it.

Comment: @insipidintegrator Yes. I think it would be interesting to see if $y(t)$ is indeed periodic, as the problem statement seems to suggest.

Comment: Normalizing to $y(t) = y_0 u(t\sqrt{g/d} )$ and letting $\alpha = y_0/d$, we get $u'' + u + \alpha (u' u)' = 0$ with $u(0) = 1, u'(0) = 0$. Do we know anything about the ratio $\alpha = y_0/d$?

Comment: @eyeballfrog No, not that I know of. $y_0$ and $d$ are 'free'.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Also, not quite sure what your substitution is meant to achieve? :-)

Comment: Mostly to reduce things down to a single parameter that determines behavior. Solving numerically seems to run into problems when $\alpha > 1/2$. Anything special about $y_0 = d/2$?

Comment: @eyeballfrog Again, not that I can see. What method are ypu using?

Comment: NDSolve in Mathematica. And actually, now that I've checked the link, I see the issue. If the initial height is larger than d/2, the height of the water column goes below the bottom of the straw, and then the whole model breaks down.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Actually, doesn't that issue arise for $y_0 \geq d$?

Comment: @Gert That would be the case if the equation were $(y+d)\ddot{y} + \dot{y}^2/2 + g y = 0$, which is what I got when I worked out the problem using Lagrangian mechanics and also is a much more well-behaved equation. For example, the conserved energy is $(y+d)\dot{y}^2 + g y^2$ instead of $(y+d)^2\dot{y}^2 + g y^2(d+2y/3)$.

Comment: You can make use of $y'=\frac{1}{x'}\implies \frac{dy'}{dy}=-\frac{x''}{[x']^2}\implies y'\frac{dy'}{dy}=y''=-\frac{x''}{[x']^3}$ which gives $-\frac{x''}{[x']^3}(d+y)+\frac{1}{[x']^2}+gy=0$ and this reduces to a linear first-order ODE by substituting $u=\frac{1}{[x']^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

The equation is time symmetric, so it will exhibit periodic motion as long as there is a turning point. That is, there is some time $t^* > 0$ such that $\dot{y}(t^*) = 0$. The period of the motion will then be $T = 2t^*$, since the path from the turning point to the start is just the time reverse of the path it took to get there.

One way to find this turning point is to see if there's an "energy" the equation conserves. This is mathematically equivalent to finding an integrating factor for the equation. In this case, we notice that $(d+y)\ddot{y} + \dot{y}^2 + g y = D_t[(d+y)\dot{y}] + g y$. By inspection, you can (sort of) see the integrating factor will be $(d+y)\dot{y}$. So then we have
\begin{multline}
(d+y)\dot{y}[(d+y)\ddot{y} + \dot{y}^2 + g y] = (d+y)\dot{y}\frac{d}{dt}[(d+y)\dot{y}] + g(d+y)y\dot{y} \\= \frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{1}{2}(d+y)^2\dot{y}^2 + \frac{gy^2}{2}\left(d+\frac{2y}{3}\right)\right] = 0
\end{multline}
Integrating this from $0$ to $t$ then gives
$$
\frac{1}{2}(d+y)^2\dot{y}^2 + \frac{gy^2}{2}\left(d+\frac{2y}{3}\right) = \frac{gy_0^2}{2}\left(d+\frac{2y_0}{3}\right).
$$
(From here out, I'm going to normalize $y$ to $y/d$ for brevity.)

This fits the form of a kinetic and potential energy adding up to a total energy, so a turning point will exist if we set $\dot{y} = 0$ and there are solutions other than $y = y_0$. These turn out to be the solutions to $y^2 +(y_0 +3/2)(y + y_0)= 0$, which has real roots if $-3/2 \le y_0\le 1/2$. This is the condition for the motion to be periodic, though admittedly $y_0 < -1$ doesn't seem very physical.

As for finding $T$, we will need the roots $y_1 , y_2$ of the above equation. Unfortunately it doesn't factor nicely, so I'll just leave them as $y_1,y_2$. The turning point will be the larger of these, which we will call $y_1$. Then to get $t^*$, we integrate $t'(y)$ between $1$ and $y_1$. Since $t'(y) = 1/\dot{y}$, we can use the energy condition to get
$$
T= 2\sqrt{\frac{3d}{2g}}\int_{y_1}^{1}\frac{(1+y)dy}{\sqrt{(y_0 - y)(y - y_1)(y-y_2)}}
$$
That's a high quality elliptic integral, but Gradshteyn and Rhyzhik have us covered, giving
$$
T = 4\sqrt{\frac{3d}{2g}}\left[\frac{1+y_2}{\sqrt{y_0-y_2}}K\left(\sqrt{\frac{y_0-y_1}{y_0-y_2}}\right) +\sqrt{y_0-y_2}E\left(\sqrt{\frac{y_0-y_1}{y_0-y_2}}\right)\right]
$$
Now this is one nasty function of $y_0$, but it is in principle calculable. Additionally, we can check two limits. For $y_0\rightarrow 0$, $T\rightarrow 2\pi\sqrt{d/g}$, as we would expect. For $y_0\rightarrow 1/2$, $T\rightarrow 6\sqrt{d/g}$. Which I'm not sure we would expect, but it's neat.

Comment: Awesome. How do we establish *'equation is time symmetric,'*?

Comment: @Gert If you replace $t\rightarrow -t$, you get the same equation. The first derivative swaps sign when you do this, but since it only shows up squared, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Ok. I'll leave this for a few days, in case someone else wants to have a go. Then I'll approve.

Comment: @Gert Is there anything about this answer you find insufficient?

Comment: Still digesting it all, really.

Comment: Hey, @eyeballfrog. Just wanted to let you know that solving for $y'$ could have been much easier by noticing $y'=\frac{1}{x'}\implies y''=-\frac{x''}{[x']^3}\implies -\frac{x''}{[x']^3}(d+y)+\frac{1}{[x']^2}+gy=0$ and we can make the substitution $u=\frac{1}{[x']^2}$ to reduce the ODE to $\frac12 (d+y)u'+u+gy=0$ which can be solved easily by multiplying by $(d+y)^2$. Then, one finds $u=[y']^2$ and can find the constant of integration by plugging in the initial conditions and we get the eliptic integral you got.

Comment: @mohamedshawkymoh That's a pretty slick derivation. I could have sworn I tried that x substitution but I guess I missed the follow-up with u. That said, I like the energy approach because its both more general and gives a physical intuition about what the turning point is.